# vfpoledb.1 gives IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005) on 2nd open

Tags: c#, sql

vfpoledb.1 gives IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005) on 2nd open
There are 2 routines that use a connection to the same database, each is called based on users selection. 
If I select the first one first, it works, and the second fails.
If I select the second one first, it works, and the first fails.
I can select either one repeatedly and it works.
Or, call the first one, second one fails, the first one works after that. 
I'm guessing that it doesn't really disconnect until the app closes, but how can I force it to close when I'm done with it the first time so that I can use it again on a different folder of dbf files in the same 'database'?

```
strFilename = "OneOfTheFoxProDBTables"
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conFPro = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=\\\\fileserver01\\dbfFolder\\;");
var sqlselect = "select id, sColumn1, sColumn2 from 'FILENAME.dbf'  ".Replace("FILENAME", strFilename);
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd3 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlselect, conFPro);
conFPro.Open();
DataSet dsDbfTableRows = new DataSet();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da3 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd3);
da3.Fill(dsDbfTableRows);  // THIS WORKS !!
conFPro.Close();   
conFPro.Dispose();  //?? Tried with and without, doesn't seem to matter.
```

Then, this in a separate method, in a separate class:

```
strFilename = "AnotherFoxProDBTables"   
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conFPro2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=\\\\fileserver02\\dbfFolder\\;");    
var sqlselect02 = "select id, sColumnA, sColumnB from 'FILENAME.dbf' ".Replace("FILENAME", strFilename);    
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd5 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlselect02, conFPro2);    
conFPro2.Open();        // <--- FAILS HERE! >>>  IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)    
DataSet dsDbfTableRows = new DataSet();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da5 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd5);
da5.Fill(dsDbfTableRows); 
conFPro2.Close();   
conFPro2.Dispose();
```

If I then swap the order that the 2 chunks of code get called, the first one will work and second will fail.

Comment: You should add some code so people can see what you're doing.

Comment: I didn't completely solve it, but I think I may have resolved it for my specific implementation. I moved the second method into the class that contained the first method, and now they both work no matter the order they're called.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the Dispose() method for the VPOLEDB provider such that it does not really dispose the resources until the app exits. Moving both methods that make use of the VPOLEDB provider to the same class makes them both work in any order.